# Allocate Pointer and pointee at once

Tags: c, allocation

If I want to reduce `malloc()`s (espacially if the data is small and allocated often) I would like to allocate the pointer and pointee at once.

If you assume something like the following:

```
struct entry {
    size_t      buf_len;
    char        *buf;
    int         something;
};
```

I would like to allocate memory in the following way (don't care about error checking here):

```
size_t buf_len  = 4;                // size of the buffer
struct entry *e = NULL;

e = malloc( sizeof(*e) + buf_len ); // allocate struct and buffer
e->buf_len  = buf_len;              // set buffer size
e->buf      = e + 1;       // the buffer lies behind the struct
```

This could even be extende, so that a whole array is allocated at once.

How would you assess such a technuique with regard to:

- Portability
- Maintainability / Extendability
- Performance
- Readability

Is this reasonable? If it is ok to use, are there any ideas on how to design a possible interface for that?

Comment: No, I think @mafso is right here. The extra allocated bytes are after the struct. So it seems like it should be `e + 1`. Otherwise, `e->buf` only points as many bytes as your point into the middle of the struct.

Comment: @mafso Shame on me!! Of course, sorry.  Edited

Comment: I really don't understand why it is not `sizeof(entry) + buf_len`.

Comment: @tucuxi the malloc size is correct, the discussion surrounded the initializer for `e->buf` .  `sizeof(struct entry)` means the same as `sizeof *e`, since the type of `*e` is `struct entry`.  `sizeof(entry)` would be an error.

Comment: @tucuxi apart from the error I like this approach more because of it's "single point of truth"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a flexible array member instead of a pointer:

```
struct entry {
    size_t      buf_len;
    int         something;
    char        buf[];
};

// ...
struct entry *e = malloc(sizeof *e  + buf_len);
e->buf_len = buf_len;
```

Portability and performance are fine. Readability: not perfect but good enough.

Extendability: you can't use this for more than one member at a time, you'd have to fall back to your explicit pointer version. Also, the explicit pointer version means that you have to muck around to ensure correct alignment if you use it with a type that doesn't have an alignment of `1`.

If you are seriously thinking about this I'd consider revisiting your entire data structure's design to see if there is another way of doing it. (Maybe this way is actually the best way, but have a good think about it first).

Comment: Thank you so much for the alignment note.

Answer (score 1):

As to portability, I am unaware of any issues, as long as the sizes are found via suitable calls to `sizeof()`, as in your code.

Regarding maintainability, extendability and readability, you should certainly wrap allocation and de-allocation in a well-commented function. Calls to...

```
entry *allocate_entry_with_buffer();
void deallocate_entry_with_buffer(entry **entry_with_buffer);
```

...do not need to know implementation details of how the memory actually gets handled. People use stranger things like custom allocators and memory pools quite frequently.

As for speed, this is certainly faster than making lots of small allocations. I used to allocate whole 2D matrices with a similar strategy...

Answer (score 1):

It should work, but in fact you are using a pointer for a useless indirection. Windows API (for example) uses another method for variable size structs : the variable size buffer is last in struct and is declared to be `char buf[1]`.

Your struct would become :

```
struct entry {
    size_t      buf_len;
    int         something;
    char        buf[1];
};
```

The allocation is (still no error checking) :

```
size_t buf_len  = 4;                // size of the buffer
struct entry *e;

e = malloc( sizeof(*e) + buf_len  - 1); // struct already has room for 1 char
e->buf_len  = buf_len;              // set buffer size
```

That's all `e.buf` is guaranteed to be a char array of size `buf_len`.

That way ensures that even if the variable part was not a character array but a int, long, or anything array, the alignement would be given by the last element being a array of proper type and size 1.

Comment: What do you mean with useless indirection

Comment: I just mean that you have a `char * buf` in your struct that you must initialize to the first character after the struct, while if you use a `char [1]` (or `char[]`) as suggested by MattMcNabb, it automatically points to the correct index after other elements in the struct.

Comment: Ah,  right.  There are two reasons for that: the first is that rhis kind of solution didn't came to my mind:-)  the second is that I also have thought of more complex struct,  where one might have multiple buffers for example.

Answer (score 0):

seems fine to me - put comments in though

Or you could do this - which is quite common

```
struct entry {
    size_t      buf_len;
    int         something;
    char        buf;
};
```

ie make the struct itself variable length. and do

```
size_t buf_len  = 4;                // size of the buffer
struct entry *e = NULL;
//  check that it packs right
e = malloc(sizeof(size_t) + sizeof(int) + buf_len ); // allocate struct and buffer
e->buf_len  = buf_len;              // set buffer size
...... later
printf(&e.buf);
```

Comment: is `sizeof(size_t)` guaranteed to be `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Sorry, didn't realize this was not a comment on my answer.

Comment: @MattMcNabb - I was being lazy - fixed

Comment: @pm100 OK. There could also be padding, to allow for that you can use `offsetof(struct entry, buf)` to get the total size up to the start of `buf`. However this approach still has the problem of causing undefined behaviour if you try to use `&e.buf` to access more than 1 byte.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, the line:

```
e->buf      = e + sizeof(*e);       // the buffer lies behind the struct
```

Should be:

```
e->buf      = e + 1;       // the buffer lies behind the struct
```

This is because `e + 1` will be equal to the address at the end of the structure. As you have it, it will only be the number of bytes into the structure equal to the number of bytes in a pointer.

And, yes, it's reasonable. However, I prefer this approach:

```
struct entry {
    size_t      buf_len;
    int         something;
    char        buf[1];
};
```

This way, you don't mess with the pointers. Just append as many bytes as needed, and they will grow the size of your `buf` array.

*Note: I wrote a text editor using an approach similar to this but used a Microsoft c++ extension that allowed me to declare the last member as `char buf[]`. So it was an empty array that was exactly as long as the number of extra bytes I allocated.*

Comment: In this version, accessing more than 1 byte of `buf` will cause undefined behaviour. Your italicized text suggests that you might have thought Standard C's flexible array member was a Microsoft extension when in fact it is standard.  It is not an empty array either, it's an incomplete type.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: First off, the technique involves allocated more memory than the size of the struct. Therefore, if you allocate enough memory for the struct plus 10 bytes, you can access 11 bytes of the `buf` array and it would not be undefined behavior. Second, I didn't follow your other statement. How can it be an incomplete type if it's now the standard.

Comment: It would be undefined behaviour: `buf` is an array of size `1` and the rules for arrays say that you cannot read beyond the end of an array (regardless of whether there happens to be allocated space there).  The actual text is 6.5.6/8 in C11  (you can view an equivalent draft called N1570), and C99 and C89 had similar text.

Comment: "incomplete type" is a subset of types. (The other ones are called "complete types").  Arrays of unknown size are an incomplete type; another common one is `void` , or `struct S;` .

Comment: @MattMcNabb: All I can tell you is that I used the Microsoft extension mentioned above to write shareware that sold thousands of copies. And Microsoft used to allow `buf[]` in this case to employ that extension. I'm a C# guy now so I can't tell you if it is still an extension, a standard or what. All I know is it is perfectly valid to access that memory because it was allocated using `malloc()`.

Comment: the `buf[]` version is valid in Standard C , and then `buf[1]` version causes undefined behaviour.  Microsoft may choose to define behaviour for the `buf[1]` case , but just saying "I did it and it seemed to work" doesn't imply that it is actually well-defined.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Well, I'm not just saying it worked. I'm saying it should work. I allocated that memory, I don't really understand why I wouldn't be able to access it. At any rate, I know stuff is getting more and more restricted to help the less capable programmers these days. So maybe things have changed since I was doing this.

Comment: If you're saying you use the `buf[]` version in your product then there is no issue with your product; the issue is only with the `buf[1]` version.

Comment: You can access memory you allocated, but not via an expression which overflows the declared bounds of an array.  Another example might be `char a[10]; char b[10];  a[15] = 'x'; ` , it causes UB even if you first check that `a` and `b` are adjacent in memory.  A compiler which implements bounds-checking could report a bounds error.

Comment: That is what is in my code. But AFAIC, if the other version has been deprecated, it would only be an issue if I recompiled. The EXE is just fine.

Comment: `buf[1]` was never legal . How would that affect your code being recompiled, since your code uses `buf[]` which is legal?

Comment: I'm saying had I used the other version, the executable would be fine because the memory being used was allocated safely. It would only be an issue if I recompiled. But I didn't use the other version.

Comment: It wouldn't be fine unless the compiler has a non-standard extension in place for this case. (IDK if it does or not). Modern compilers such as gcc certainly don't; they will optimize based on the fact that out-of-bounds array accesses is not permitted.