# Potential issues with p* in structs?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, buffer

I have been churning through C for the last several months. In an effort to learn the language, the project is an arithmetic parser - formulas, variables, etc.

I recently decided to go ahead and work out garbage collection because I have a lot of calls to this method:

```
char* read_token(const Source* source, const Token* token) {
    int szWord = token->t_L + 1;        //  +1 for NULL terminator
    char* word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*szWord);
    memset(word, '\0', sizeof(char)*(szWord));
    char* p_T = source->p_Src + token->t_S;
    memcpy(word, p_T, token->t_L);

    return word;
}
```

... which means calling `free(...)` quite a bit.

The `Source` struct has two buffer properties among others:

```
typedef struct source Source;
struct source {
    // ...
    char* p_Src;            // malloc'd source buffer
    int srcLen;
    Token* p_tokens;        // malloc'd Token buffer
    // ...
};
```

The `Token` struct has *start* and *length* properties:

```
typedef struct token Token;
struct token {
    int t_S;                // buffer start index
    int t_L;                // token length
};
```

In addition, since there could be many `source`s, a `Source*` buffer is `malloc`'d.
When a buffer is `malloc`'d, the size of the struct is provided (`* numStructs`). But if a given struct has a buffer that may be allocated at a later time, such as `Token*`, does that change the size of `Source`? Is the code in danger of overwriting previously allocated memory?

For some reason I was getting the idea that all of the memory used for a struct, including any buffers, is allocated in a linear manner. If `Token*` buffer in struct is allocated to 10 tokens, that space is not then linearly allocated within the `Source` struct right?

Comment: If you've got pointers in there that have been malloced, then the struct is clearly not 'linear':(

Comment: A pointer in a `struct` is a fixed size, regardless of what it is pointing at, even if it is uninitialised.  When `malloc` is used, the memory is taken somewhere from the heap, we know not where, and should not care either.  Obviously (?) you should call `free()` on the pointer before the struct that it lives in is destroyed.

Comment: @cdarke: that makes sense. Provide that as the answer and I'll accept it. Like I said, for some reason my mind wanted to shove the buffer into the linear memory allocated for the encapsulating struct. :S

Comment: The struct holds a set of variables of fixed size. Some of them happen to be pointers. What they point to has no effect on their size. With `malloc` you don't allocate memory *within* the struct. You allocate memory independently on the heap (somewhere *outside*), and set the pointers to point at that memory. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pointer in a struct is a fixed size, regardless of what it is pointing at, even if it is uninitialised. That way, `sizeof(struct token)` is a fixed length.

When `malloc` is used, the memory is taken somewhere from the heap, we know not where, and should not care either.  It is highly unlikely that memory will be allocated anywhere near the original struct, and even if it was, that would be implementation specific and you could not count on that behaviour.

Obviously (?) you should call `free()` on the pointer before the struct that it lives in is destroyed.

Also note C99's [Variable Length Arrays](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) (VLAs).

Answer (score 1):

The pointer members in your `struct` are variables that store addresses of memory blocks and as you state yourself pointers and pointees are **allocated independently**. Hence those buffers might be located just next to where their 'parent' `struct` is stored, or not (and most probably won't).

**If it is needed**, ensuring contiguous storage of the `struct` members and its pointed buffers can be achieved by allocating everything in one call to the `*alloc` function.

This can be done

- using fixed-size buffers: not really convenient since any flexibility on the buffer sizes is lost. Also note that declaring this updates the value of `sizeof(struct foo)` accordingly.
- using C99's **flexible array member** or tricks to enable the feature in pre-C99 C: [Allocate Pointer and pointee at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29088176/allocate-pointer-and-pointee-at-once) .
- using not recommended hacks resorting on pointer arithmetic, watching out for the compiler's alignment policy.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i'm writing this in the "Answer" section instead of "Comments" section because my Stackoverflow reputation isn't high enough yet.
What i was about to comment is Why don't you just use this line:

```
char word[ sizeof(char)*szWord ];
```

instead of

```
char* word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*szWord); ?
```

Comment: As an example of **variable length arrays** as @cdarke suggests? I can give that a try. Thanks!